# JD Edwards Enterprise One 9.1 Biztalk Adapter

Tags: java, oracle11g, biztalk, jdedwards, biztalk-2013

I am trying to connect Biztalk 2013 to JD Edwards Enterprise One 9.1 Standalone Demo (oracle version).

I have configured all the parameters as it is said in this thread http://mikearnett.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/biztalk-jde-enterpriseone-adapter-configuration-tips/

And I have looked through a lot of information on the web, but just can't understand how JD Edwards data sources work, how and where to create them? And the main question is how to fill properties of biztalk adapter correctly, such as 'Bootstrap Data Source Required Properties'?

My current error in error log is:

**E-JDE0010: JNI invocation method failed for the method GetModulePrefixes. JDEdwards error message : com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.spec.SpecFailureException: Fail to connect to oneworld source com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.spec.dbservices.BSFNLookupFailureException: Fail to fetch LibraryInfos [OCM_DEFAULT_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND] The OCM does not contain a default entry for environment DEMO910.**

Maybe someone knows where to read information about this topic or have an experience in connecting Biztalk to JD Edwards?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using adapters to integrate with JDE, consider using web services and do everything that you need to do (in JDE) within web service. The reason for this is performance. Lets say that you want to call 3 business functions for a given integration: If you call them directly from BizTalk (or any external application), you will incur the performance penalty of the latency between BizTalk and JDE. Instead, if you wrap these functions in a web service and call the web service from BizTalk, those functions will run within the context of JDE. This is a simplistic example, but you get the general idea.

For JDE web services, you have (at least) two options: Java Based Business Services or .Net Based Web Services, part of LynX Business Integrator (see http://youtube.com/user/aelliuslynx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that OCM table has an active record for DEMO910 environment for the user or role or *PUBLIC in order to resolve following exception

com.jdedwards.system.connector.dynamic.spec.dbservices.BSFNLookupFailureException: Fail to fetch LibraryInfos [OCM_DEFAULT_ENTRY_NOT_FOUND]